# How to remove ghost indices from ElasticSuite?

Tags: magento2, search, indexing, magento2.4.5

I'm using ElasticSuite and suddenly this message below appeared.

[image: You have 22 ghost indices. Ghost indices have a footprint on your Elasticsearch cluster health. You should consider removing them.]

[image: Magento Ghost indices]

What's ghost indices and how can I avoid having them?

Answer (score 0):

If you know what are the ghost indices then you can follow the below

You have to send a DELETE request to

```
http://[your_host]:9200/[your_index_name_here]
```

**Using cURL**

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/index/type/documentID
```

e.g.

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/shop/catalog/1
```

You will then receive a reply as to whether this was successful or not. You can delete an entire index or types with an index also, you can delete a type by leaving out the document ID like so -

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/shop/product
```

If you wish to delete an index -

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/shop
```

Answer (score 0):

Ghost indices indicate that the fulltext indexing process did not end well.

You should check in the Magento logs (**exception.log** or **system.log**) to see if there are any logged errors during re-indexing. Or maybe check also the ElasticSearch server logs.

You can safely remove these indices, they are not used by the engine.

You just need to install this module to automatically clean your ghost indices based on a cronjob execution. But keep in mind that clean this up is just a work around, you need to find out why your reindex process is not finishing.

```
composer require sehrling/elasticsuite-ghost-cleaner
bin/magento module:enable Sehrling_ElasticsuiteGhostCleaner
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

References:

- [Too Many Indices with Status as Ghots](https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite/issues/2106)
- [ElasticSuite tracking indices causes problems with Elasticsearch](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/kb/troubleshooting/elasticsearch/elasticsuite-tracking-indices-causes-problems-with-elasticsearch.html?lang=en)
- [Elasticsuite-ghost-cleaner module](https://github.com/stephanie-ehrling/elasticsuite-ghost-cleaner)